# Is there alternative for CIFIlter to generate QR code in watch os 6

Tags: swift, watch, watchos-6

I am developing a watch independant app.
I want to generate QRcode on watchkit, but since coreImage doesnt work with watchkit, is there any other way we can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Anup, Have you find any solution for generating QR code in a standalone watch app?

Answer (score 3):

I use libraries, which supported watch os.

For example [EFQRCode](https://github.com/EFPrefix/EFQRCode)

Answer (score 1):

I've a QR Code appearing in a Watch App.

I generated it as a UIImage -- encoded it as a Base64 String and send it across to the Watch as Data using WatchConnectivity. This does use CIFiter but only the Phone side to generate a UIImage.

On the Watch I decoded the UIImage from the Data.

Comment: It's a nice method but it doesn't work efficiently. both apps must be running for this method to work properly